# Android SQLITE database no internet

Tags: java, android, sqlite, external

I am new to Android programming and looking for the best way of working with an sqlite database. I need to be able to load a database into the app and enter data then export. I will need to be able to do this without an internet connection. I been looking at examples and how to's and reading everything I can.

I am seeing a lot on loading the database and having the app copy it into a system database leaving you with 2 database.

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

however I think what I am looking for is a way to work directly with the database possibly attached to the sd card. once data is entered the user could connect via usb and copy and email the database. *remember there will be no internet connection. On the other hand a database could be copied onto the sd card and the app will be able to read and write to it.
Maybe this is not the best way? or do I have to use 2 databases?

I am not looking for anyone to step by step me but better yet guide me in the correct direction. maybe links to some tuts or articles would be very helpful. Thanks everyone!!

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Forget about the fact that there will be no Internet connection, that is irrelevant. SQLite will work just fine with no Internet connection; why do you think it requires one?

Comment: I have a team that will be at the start of the day going out into the field and collecting data samples. These will be entered into the database and at the end of the day sent to myself in order to update our system with. This information is needed to be compiled nightly and right now they have to take everything down by hand then either pay someone to do lots of data entry or enter it in every night. I would like to streamline this process using an app. BTW I am having a blast learning android! :)

Comment: I would have a web service on the internal network that the applications push data to each evening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create your database, you need to specify a path, rather than allowing the app to create a database where it would normally reside.

Modify your DB helper class to reflect these changes:

```
private final static DB_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
private final static DB_NAME = "my_database";

public DBHelper(Context ctx)
{
    database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH + "/" + DB_NAME, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}
```

Now you have a database on your SD card and nothing in the traditional location.  You might wish to consider simply keeping the working database in the traditional location for the sake of redundancy, if it's not too large.  SD cards fail, devices fail, etc., so copying the database to SD card would give you a level of insurance.

Comment: one other question i am reading that the primary must be _id is this correct? In my database I do have my primaries set to others. Am i able to use these or does the DB Helper have to have the _id?

Comment: Stack Overflow discourages extended discussions.  Try to keep each question to its own separate Q&A so that people searching for answers get exactly what they need, nothing more, nothing less.